# A suffix is ​added to my url of docker build and result a timeout

Tags: docker, build, timeout, artifactory

I don't know why but my env add a /v2 after my link to my artifactory like :

dockerfile :

**FROM docker-registry.test.fr/test-base/alpine:3.12 as dependencies**

and when i call : **docker build --build-arg USER_CI=USER --build-arg PASSWORD_CI=PASSWORD -t wso2-docker .**

I have :

**Sending build context to Docker daemon  138.8kB
Step 1/18 : FROM docker-registry.test.fr/test-base/alpine:3.12 as dependencies
Get "https://docker-registry.test.fr/v2/": dial tcp: lookup docker-registry.test.fr on 192.168.1.148:53: read udp 192.168.49.2:54471->192.168.1.148:53: i/o timeout**

Do you know where is define this url ?

Thx.

Comment: `/v2` is the HTTP path used by the [Docker registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about registry path health? would can be accessed?

verify by pulling the image:
docker pull yourImageRegistryRepoUrl

Comment: yes, https://docker-registry.test.fr is ok with my logins but not https://docker-registry.test.fr/v2 !

Comment: like **docker pull https://docker-registry.test.fr** (sorry, i'm a beginner)

Comment: The timeout indicates for something not reachable at the moment - To trace the problem you should also ensure the if you have the proxy, if yes, would it be working for you.. see relevant configuration in ubuntu  cat ~/.docker/config.json

Comment: I undertand, my url **https://docker-registry.test.fr** is reachable with my logins by chrome but not with a suffixe /V2 at the end !

Answer (score 0):

How you have setup the Artifactory with docker? what docker access method you are using to connect? /v2 endpoint is expected as docker client expects v2 requests. The issue here is docker does not know if "docker-registry.test.fr" is available based onn what docker access method is set up.

Comment: Where i can found this setup?

Comment: I would recommend referring to these wikis, https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry and https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-we-change-docker-access-method-to-repository-path-and-what-are-the-advantages/

Comment: Basically, you should first confirm what docker access method is being used by navigating to Admin --> Services | Artifactory --> HTTP settings and changing the docker access method to repository path for now. The assuming you are accessing Artifactory UI as https://docker-registry.test.fr, you should be able to login to Artifactory via docker as "docker login docker-registry.test.fr" with repository path selected earlier. Once login is successful, assuming your docker repository is "docker-local" and the image is "myimage", then use "docker pull docker-registry.test.fr/docker-local/myimage"

Answer (score 0):

I've update my ca-certificates.crt and it's ok now !
Thx.